# How to call method on component that is being transitioned to with Navigator in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My main navigation component looks like this:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
         views: [
            { title: 'Page 1', component: React.createElement(PageOne) },
            { title: 'Page 2', component: React.createElement(PageTwo) },
            { title: 'Page 3', component: React.createElement(PageThree) }
         ],
         currentView: 'Page 1'
      };
   }
   changeScene(data) {
      if (this.refs.navigator.getCurrentRoutes().find(r => r.title === data.title))
         this.refs.navigator.jumpTo(data);
      else
         this.refs.navigator.push(data);
      this.setState({currentView: data.title});
   }
   renderScene(route, navigator) {
      return route.component;
   }
   render() {
      return (
         <View>
            <Navigator
               ref="navigator"
               style={{flex: 1}}
               initialRoute={this.state.views[0]}
               renderScene={this.renderScene} />
         </View>
      );
   }
};
```

I would like to call a method (something like `onTransitionedTo`) on a Page component once it is transitioned to in the Navigator. I tried the following:

```
   changeScene(data) {
      if (this.refs.navigator.getCurrentRoutes().find(r => r.title === data.title))
         this.refs.navigator.jumpTo(data);
      else
         this.refs.navigator.push(data);
      this.setState({currentView: data.title});

      if (data.component.onTransitionedTo)
         data.component.onTransitionedTo();
   }
```

But that obviously doesn't work. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try executing a passed callback on componentWillMount or some other appropriate lifecycle method so that the component is the one that checks if it's been transitioned to rather than the parent trying to execute something on the child directly.

In Main:

```
React.createElement(PageOne, { isActive: () => this._isActive(PageOne) })
...
_isActive(component) {
    let routes = this.refs.navigator.getCurrentRoutes();
    return component === routes[routes.length - 1];
}
```

In component:

```
componentWillMount() {
    if (this.props.isActive()) { 
        // Set state to affect render 
    }
}
```

Comment: `componentWillMount` won't be called though when the scene is already rendered once

Comment: I wasn't trying to be specific/exclusive with `componentWillMount`.  You could even call it from render or pass a prop and update that....  Point stands: invert where the behavior lies and put it in your child component, rather than trying to execute something internal to it from the parent.